# How to Make Point Lamps Cast Shadows in Blender Internal Render Viewport?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, 3d-view, shaders

I am trying to showcase how well OpenGL rendering works for complex scenes and with advanced shading while still rendering extremely fast. I wanted to display the power of being able to use GLSL viewport to get a real-time and accurate display of what the final render will look like with cast shadows and normals. I have run into a problem however with the point light because it does not cast a shadow which I need for every light in my interior house scene. Currently I am using several spot lamps pointed in various directions to give the same effect which works but is not nearly as convenient as using a single lamp. Does anyone have an idea on how to do this?

Comment: This is not supported in Blender at the moment as far as I know. Upcoming Blender 2.8 viewport rewrite might eventually support this.

Comment: Duarte is right, though using *spot lamps* can produce quite nice results. Switching to **blender game** gives you the extra option to soften the shadows, which makes the glsl render look more realistic. Please check out this tut: https://cgcookie.com/2015/05/20/pbr-in-blenders-viewport/